# bootstrap 4 auto width absolute position in display flex

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I have a `div` and set display to `flex` using bootstrap 4. then I add another `div` into it and set `position` to `absolute` and `rotate` it using `transform`. like this:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="area d-flex position-relative">
    <div class="title">
      title
    </div>
    <div>
      content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
.inner {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.title {
  transform: rotate(-90deg) !important;
  position: absolute;
  left: -20px;
  top: 43px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 12px;
  background-color: #000;
  width: auto;
}
```

I set `width` to `auto` to resize `width` of `div` with `absolute` position auto. but in action it doesn't work. How do can I fix this problem?

I need to this:

[image]

Edited DEMO:

Demo [Here](https://jsfiddle.net/4jk1s6r8/)

Comment: What is your expected output? It is working absolutely fine as you wrote the code. It is rotated 90deg and it's position also set to absolute.

Comment: @ShashankGb: see new updated

Comment: Why can't you just use `border-left` instead of these messy `d-flex`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I thought it can be done with `border-left` instead of `d-flex` which makes more complicate when we compare both and both gives same output

My approach is give `<div>content</div>` a `border-left` which creates a **black vertical rectangle** and `rotate` a `<div>title</div>` with `270deg` and make it center using `top:50%; transform: translateY(-50%);` but it's position should be `absolute`

```css
.wrapper{
  padding-left: 1rem;
  border-left: 40px solid black;
  position: absolute;
}

.title{
  position: absolute;
  color: white;
  letter-spacing: 2px;
  font-size: 12px;
  left: -5%;
  top: 50%;
  transform: translateY(-50%) rotate(270deg);
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="wrapper">
      <div class='title'>title</div>
    <div>
      content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content 
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

**Updated:  Responsive Design Code**

Since a height value of `.content` should be assigned as width to `.title`, a little bit of JavaScript is needed and added that in the code snippet below.(As far as I know, it's not possible through pure CSS).

```js
let eleHeight = document.getElementById('content').offsetHeight;
let titleEle = document.getElementById('title');
titleEle.style.minWidth = eleHeight+"px";
```

```css
.wrapper{
    padding: 4rem;
}

.inner{
    display: flex;
   position: relative;
}

.side-text{
    color: white;
    position: absolute;
    transform: rotate(90deg);
    transform-origin: top left;
}

.title{
    text-align: center;
    background-color: black;
  margin: auto; 
}

.content{
    padding-left: 1rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='wrapper'>
    <div class='inner'>
          <div class='side-text'>
              <div id='title' class='title'>title title title</div>
          </div>
          <div id='content' class='content'>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
          </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I think, it's doesn't work truly in responsive mode(resize window), and text title moving on resize.

Comment: @CodeCover Well you didn't mentioned so i didn't considered `responsive-design`. I will updated the answer check out.

Comment: your code work only for `title` text. if we have a `title` with more words, eg: `title title title`. the 'side-text' doesn't work true and resized.

Comment: Please Mention your complete expected solution once, You are simply adding your requirements. So please mention all your expected result at once

Comment: @CodeCover I am updated the answer again. A little bit of JavaScript is needed to assign height value of `.content` to width `.title`. I think now I completed your request

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to use transform. Use `flex-row` with `d-flex` to achieve it.

```css
.inner {
  background: #f1f1f1;
}

.title {
  background-color: #000;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-B0vP5xmATw1+K9KRQjQERJvTumQW0nPEzvF6L/Z6nronJ3oUOFUFpCjEUQouq2+l" crossorigin="anonymous">

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.5.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-DfXdz2htPH0lsSSs5nCTpuj/zy4C+OGpamoFVy38MVBnE+IbbVYUew+OrCXaRkfj" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@4.6.0/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-Piv4xVNRyMGpqkS2by6br4gNJ7DXjqk09RmUpJ8jgGtD7zP9yug3goQfGII0yAns" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<!-- 
  Bootstrap docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs
-->

<div class="container">
  <div class="inner d-flex flex-row">
    <div class="title">
      title
    </div>
    <div>
      content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content content
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Reference

[Bootstrap - Flex](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/utilities/flex/)

Comment: u right, but I need to show title text vertically and center of `div`